# Rails 3 - routing to a controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, routes

heres what I'm currently using:
`Rails -v 3.2.3`

I'm trying to make a path in routes.rb that will route to a method in my links_controller.rb.

**routes.rb**

`match 'modify_points' => 'links#modify_points', :as => :modify_points`

**links_controller.rb method**

```
def modify_points
  @link = Link.find(params[:id])
  @link.update_attribute :points, @link.points + params[:by].to_i if params[:by] =~ /[+|-]?1/
  render_text @link.points
end
```

here is how i am calling the method in my view:

`<%= link_to('UP', modify_points_path(link, :by => 1), :remote => true) %>`

however when i click on this `UP` link.... nothing happens. what should happen is link.points should increase by 1, however when i check in the console, my points are still at zero. am i creating the routes correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have always used something like this:

match '/modify_points' => 'link#modify_points', :as => 'modify_points'

Does that generate the route you want? What does rake routes show?

Comment: rakes routes shows this `modify_points    /modify_points(.:format)  links#modify_points` which i believe to be the correct route? however it is not increasing my points so i must have written the method wrong

Comment: if the `modify_points` method is inside of my `links_controller` ... shouldn't the route be something like `/links/:id/modify_points(.:format)` ? .... sorry still new to rails

Comment: Something is odd. Your routes show 'links#modify_points' but you have 'link#modify_points'

Comment: whoops yeah that was a typo on my part haha sorry!

Comment: Yes, those little typos are hard to see! :)